# OutOfMemoryError in XML JDOM parser in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, out-of-memory, jdom

Developing dictionary application for Android. There is a database in XML file. It is quite large(72MB) to parse with DOM parser. Trying to parse it with JDOM parser:

```
List<org.jdom2.Element> list = null;
try {
    File db = new File(UnZip.DATABASE_PATH);
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(db);
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

    //HERE CODE IS GETTING STUCK
    Document document = (Document) builder.build(stream);
    org.jdom2.Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
    list = rootNode.getChildren(ENTRY_TAG);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JDOMException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (Element node : list) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, node.getChildText(ENT_SEQ));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, node.getChildText(REB));
}
```

This code is giving OutOfMemory error:

> 06-05 12:45:58.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10068): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-05 12:45:58.788: E/AndroidRuntime(10068):
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted] 06-05 12:45:58.788:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10068):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

I assume that code is getting stuck here:

```
Document document = (Document) builder.build(stream);
```

How to avoid this error and find needed entry from whole XML file(170000 entries)?

Comment: Use Sax or Pull parser. It especially designed for large XML files

Comment: Isn't JDOM Parser modified version(where less code is written) of XMLPullParser? I will try SAX parser.

Comment: Recommended use http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html as more simpler and newer.

Comment: What do you think? `xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );` How can I take Xml String from file and at the same time, avoid OutOfMemory error? I mean instead of "<foo>Hello World!</foo>"

Comment: use `setInput (InputStream)`. It will be ok, without loading all document in memory

Comment: SAX parser is returning this error `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The parser has encountered more than "64 000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDOM, like DOM, XOM, and all other in-memory-xml-model libraries will represent the entire XML document in memory. If you consider that most XML documents are singe-byte-encoded (UTF-8 or ASCII) and that is then converted to 2-byte chars in Java/Android, it is normal for in-memory XML representations to take about twice as much memory as the raw XML document.

Compared to others, JDOM is pretty respectful of memory usage (I am the maintainer, I am biased, but I have also tried really, really hard on the memory management side).

You could try using [the SlimJDOMFactory](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/SlimJDOMFactory.html) as part of your document build, but that will not save you as much as you will need.

The same problem exists for all in-memory XML models, and (for different document sizes) on all platforms and system configurations.

The solutions are:

- find out [how much memory you re allowed](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html)
- don't have such big documents. A 72Meg document on Android seems .... redundant.
- to not parse the entire document at once, and to use streaming systems for parsing (SAX, etc)
- off-load the processing to a server app.
- others.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) class, as DarkDarker suggested. Use either the setInput() that takes a Reader or the one that takes an InputStream and an encoding name (probably "UTF-8"). Then you can just use the parser to move through the document one element at a time, building your list as you go.

All DOM approaches (including JDOM, dom4j, and others) are memory hogs since they build the entire document representation in memory. The actual memory usage is typically at least 4x the byte size of the document, between the overhead of strings (two bytes per character) and the overhead of objects for every component of the document.